# How to widen all live buffers?

Tags: buffers, narrowing

I'd like to apply e.g. `widen` to all active buffers, rather than the current one.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Iterate among all buffers that are displayed (i.e., have a window), widening each:

```lisp
(defun foo ()
  "..."
  (interactive)
  (dolist (buf  (buffer-list))
    (when (get-buffer-window buf 0)
      (with-current-buffer buf (widen)))))
```

Or if you want to do it to all (live) buffers, even if they aren't displayed in a window, then this:

```lisp
(defun foo ()
  "..."
  (interactive)
  (dolist (buf  (buffer-list))
    (when (buffer-live-p buf)
      (with-current-buffer buf (widen)))))
```